# Electric current through loop of wire

Tags: magnetic-fields

We have an electric current running through a wire loop, then we are interested in the magnetic field  generated by this current (moving charges). The main question is, the value of the magnetic field at how many points needs to be known in order to infer the position of the center of the loop?

Comment: Do you know the shape of the loop? Do you know the size?

Comment: Do you know the magnitude of the magnetic field, or do you have the direction as well?

Comment: @Floris Circular loop, say of radius $r.$ I'm wondering about the case where only the magnitude of the field is given at some points (how many is the question) and from them one tries to infer the center of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle your loop has five degrees of freedom - three for the location of the center and two for the direction it is pointing. This means you need five measurements to solve in general. If you don't know the current you need six points.